# Live OS doesn't see USB mouse or keyboard

Tags: installation, keyboard, uefi

I have a new Gigabyte 970A-D3 with an AMD Phenom II CPU and I'm trying to install an OS.  This is not my first rodeo installing Linux.
I've tried booting to the live OS for Ubuntu 12.10 and Lubuntu 12.10 and after it loads the OS, the mouse and keyboard do not respond.  The USB mouse and keyboard work fine inside the BIOS and during language selection for the Live CDs.  I've tried different USB ports, still no good.
This is a UEFI motherboard, but I'm not booting to UEFI mode. Are there any BIOS settings I can look at that might help?

Note: Legacy USB support is enabled.  I have tried different mice and keyboards. When I get to the screen that allows me to either *Try* or *Install* Ubuntu, the keyboard works fine. A PS2 mouse works.

Comment: Terminal is pretty useless without a keyboard, I forgot about that lol. Going to remove my answer to get your question unanswered. I also missed the point where you say you can select language. It then is not a BIOS issue.

Comment: Can you please add the USB ID for the keyboard and mouse (output from **lusub**), to assist others.

Comment: I couldn't get output from lsusb.  The keyboard did not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue. The trick is to enable (at least on Gigabyte Motherboards like the 970a series) IOMMU in the peripherials tab. It is ab option with no description close to the bottom of the menu. Only 2 options, enable or disable. Enable the option save the setting and reboot. Surprise! All of you USB devices are now functional again. More about IOMMU [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-turn-on-linux-software-iommu-support.html)

Comment: That motherboard has been sitting on a shelf for 2 months.  Can't wait to try this solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much.  If you're ever in Manchester, UK I'll buy you a beer.

I've already driven out to PC World to buy a new keyboard and mouse thinking that the problem might be to do with my wireless drivers. grrrr....

Comment: In my case with a Gigabyte motherboard from ~2008, there wasn't any option for IOMMU in the peripherals menu, but there were a pair of options for "Enable USB keyboard" and "Enable USB mouse" in that menu which did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really was to replace the motherboard/CPU.  Maybe it was the combination of the two models I bought.  I replaced them with an Intel i5 and an MSI motherboard. Everything worked out of the box.