# Mouse and Ethernet not responding

Tags: installation, networking, mouse

I just tried to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8 and the mouse and ethernet did not work during installation and continued not on to work when it was completed.
The keyboard works fine but it seems like I have to connect it to a USB 3 port.
The mouse doesn't respond anywhere.
My motherboard is  Gigabyte 970A-DS3.

Also,I tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 with the same results (I didn't finish the installation, I still have the 13.04 on my system).

Any suggestions? On windows 8 all USB ports work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be sorted out by following the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281964/live-os-doesnt-see-usb-mouse-or-keyboard?rq=1).

*"Basically, It is an option which no description close to the bottom of the menu. Only 2 options, enable or disable. Enable the option save the setting and reboot."*